# Mobile navigation menu doesn't work

Tags: jquery, sass, responsive-design, pug

I can't seem to make `nav ul` slide down when I click on the `#navicon-1` element.

I'm using SASS and PUG in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/make96/pen/Brdmbq)   and below is the *compiled* version:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
nav ul {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: black;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  #nav-icon1 {
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transitions: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transitions: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transform: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transform: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 9px;
    opacity: 1;
    background: black;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transitions: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transitions: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transitions: 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 36px;
  }

  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #nav-icon1.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div id="nav-icon1"><span></span><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: You're adding the `.open` class to `#nav-icon1`, and you want it to effect a UL that's not a child of `#nav-icon1`? You'll need to target the element you want to show/hide. Perhaps adding some classes to elements you wish to target would make the code / question a bit clearer.

Comment: Yes, I want to display the `nav` when the `#nav-icon1` is `open`.

In this current state I want it to be hidden, but my code got way too complicated for me and I have no idea what I'm doing anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple things missing here. Firstly, to show / hide an element, you'll need to start with it either shown / hidden. I assume you want to hide the menu between `360px` and `767px` as seen in your media query, and if you want it to *slide* down it needs to be up! Adding the `.nav` class to the UL makes it easier to target with the following SASS:

```
.nav
  position: absolute
  top: -100%
  transition: top 500ms
  &.open
    top: 0
```

You can see here that adding the `.open` class will slide the menu back down from the top, and the `transition` property will animate this over 500ms.

You will also need to move the button that shows / hides this menu outside of this menu's wrapper, or it will be hidden, too. You can see in the following PUG code how this works, with the above `.nav` class added:

```
#nav-icon1
  span
  span
  span
  span
nav#nav-menu.nav
  ul
    li
      a(href="#") Lorem
    li
      a(href="#") Lorem
    li
      a(href="#") Lorem
    li
      a(href="#") Lorem
```

And lastly your JavaScript will have to toggle the `.open` class on both the button *and* the menu you want to show / hide. Which is why I've added, the #nav-menu ID above. Here's an example of that using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $navMenu = $('#nav-menu');

  $('#nav-icon1').click(function(){
    $(this).add($navMenu).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

[Here's a fork](https://codepen.io/benjibee/pen/oqeEMv) of your original CodePen, please review my changes and consider how you'd implement them in your own project!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate for taking your time and helping me out. I really appreciate it. Luckily I've managed to make it work, but my solution isn't as elegant as yours.

Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Glad to hear it! If my answer has helped you, please consider marking it as an accepted answer so others might see my solution :)